# Is it a Security Issue in Codeigniter which Allow to Run Controller Functions using URL?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am not sure that this is a security  issue or I understand something wrongly? That's why I ask this question.

As I understood, Anyone can run any controller function using URL. Assume that I have a controller function called `delete` in controller called `user`.

So anyone can run that function using

```
http://example.com/index.php/user/delete
```

Is it a securty issue?

I mean in pure PHP, you can't run any function via URL even you know the custom function name.

But seems like anyone can run any function in Codeigniter Controller if they know the controller name and function name. Is it a security issue or I understand something wrongly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're misunderstanding. When you pass a URL to CodeIgniter, you aren't directly executing a custom function. CI takes the URL, breaks it into pieces and figures out how to route it based on default handling and any custom routing that you have configured. You can throw together a quick and dirty setup that works in a similar fashion without using CI. This kind of setup isn't unique to CI or even to PHP itself.

This behavior is not a security concern. USER INPUT+DEVELOPER RESPONSE is the security concern. How you handle that delete call and the data that's passed into is where the potential security problem becomes relevant.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you give of a `delete` method there is a potential for mischief. You don't show a parameter being sent to `delete` but one would be required in order to identify the user to be deleted. A hostile operator could call `delete` and try random user id values. To be "secure" some kind of authentication/permission system must be in place where the delete method does not proceed unless the user is known and has appropriate permission.

The same applies to any "add", "edit" and possibly "view" methods dealing with "users".

Really, any UI that deals with creating, updating, reading, and deleting (CRUD) any data should have an authentication/permissions system in place.

This need is not unique to CodeIgniter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `Really, any UI that deals with creating, updating, reading, and deleting (CRUD) any data should have an authentication/permissions system in place` -- I am agree with that and I have already implement that. My question was in pure PHP others can't run any custom function using URL, But in codeigniter it is possible........

Answer (score -1):

it's no any security issue.
But you say you use delete function so set any delete parameter value.
if use any parameter for delete any row value then use as below url format
http://www.example.com/index.php/user/delete/id/1
may be it's work. or describe more in details then i help to you.